# how to check if kubernetes services like mysql, rabbitmq are reachable by the deployed app

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I am new to Kubernetes. I am trying to deploy a microservices architecture based springboot web application in Kubernetes. I have setup Kubernetes on OpenStack. All Kubernetes services are running fine.

I followed https://github.com/fabric8io/gitcontroller/tree/master/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/examples/javaweb-tomcat-sidecar

to deploy a sample springboot application at

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

and I could see the web app at `localhost:8080` and `<'node-ip'>:8080`.

But the application which I am trying to deploy needs MySQL and rabbitmq, so I created MySQL and rabbitmq services using the `yaml` file(*javaweb.yaml*):

javaweb.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # Expose the management HTTP port on each node
  name: rabbitmq-management
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: NodePort # Or LoadBalancer in production w/ proper security
  ports:
  - port: 15672
    name: http
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The required headless service for StatefulSets
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    name: amqp
  - port: 4369
    name: epmd
  - port: 25672
    name: rabbitmq-dist
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: javaweb
spec:
  containers:
  - image: chakravarthych/sample:v1
    name: war
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /app
      name: app-volume
  - image: mysql:5.7
    name: mysql
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      containerPort: 3306
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: root123
    command: ["sh","-c","service mysql start; tail -f /dev/null"]
  - image: rabbitmq:3.7-management
    name: rabbitmq
    ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      containerPort: 15672
    - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      containerPort: 5672
    command: ["sh","-c","service rabbitmq-server start; tail -f /dev/null"]
  - image: tomcat:8.5.33
    name: tomcat
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      name: app-volume
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      hostPort: 8080
    command: ["sh","-c","/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh; tail -f /dev/null"]
  volumes:
  - name: app-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

When I try to access my application at `localhost:8080` or <'node-ip'>:8080 I see a blank page.

command `kubectl get all -o wide` gave me below output:

```
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE         NOMINATED NODE
pod/javaweb   4/4       Running   0          1h        192.168.9.123   kube-node1   <none>

NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       AGE       SELECTOR
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                       3d        <none>
service/mysql                 NodePort    10.101.253.11   <none>        3306:30527/TCP                1h        app=mysql
service/rabbitmq              ClusterIP   None            <none>        5672/TCP,4369/TCP,25672/TCP   1h        app=rabbitmq
service/rabbitmq-management   NodePort    10.108.7.162    <none>        15672:30525/TCP               1h        app=rabbitmq
```

which shows that MySQL and rabbitmq are running.

**My question is how to check if my application has access to MySQL and rabbitmq services running in Kubernetes.**

Note:

I could access rabbitmq at 192.168.9.123:15672 only.

I could also log in to MySQL inside of Docker container.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to get shell access to your pod "javaweb":
`kubectl exec -it javaweb -- /bin/bash`

Comment: @hplus I get shell access to each container in the pod, no problem in that.

Comment: after you have shell access, try to access to your MySQL service via mysql client, and rabbitmq via REST api. If that works, your application will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a "kubectl log" on the springboot pod? You may have some indication of what is going wrong.

Comment: yes, I checked the logs with "kubectl log". I see no issues in them.

Comment: @Chakri As stated in the comment of your first post, try to connect to the the srpingboot pod and then try to curl, telnet the other container to test if you can speak to them.